# Flutter Web: Can't get authorized client with Google Drive API

Tags: dart, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, flutter-web

```
Error: Failed to get user consent: idpiframe_initialization_failed.


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:56990/dart_sdk.js:4368:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:56990/dart_sdk.js:38289:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:56990/dart_sdk.js:38283:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:56990/dart_sdk.js:38115:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:56990/dart_sdk.js:38121:13)
    at http://localhost:56990/dart_sdk.js:33618:9
```

Browser shows the window to login but throw the error above simultaneously, and don't wait the response from user.

```
import "package:googleapis_auth/auth_browser.dart";

var id = new auth.ClientId('APP_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com', null);
var scopes = [drive.DriveApi.DriveFileScope, drive.DriveApi.DriveScope];

createImplicitBrowserFlow(id, scopes).then((BrowserOAuth2Flow flow) {
  flow.clientViaUserConsent().then((AuthClient client) {

    print(client); // never execute this
    client.close();
    flow.close();
  });
});
```

For Android/iOS I'm using `auth_io.dart` with no problem

Comment: Is it because you are using `null` as your Client Secret?

Answer (score 0):

This relates to `obtainAccessCredentialsViaUserConsent` and is expected behaviour:

https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis_auth/latest/auth_browser/BrowserOAuth2Flow/obtainAccessCredentialsViaUserConsent.html

> If immediate is true there will be no user involvement. If the user is
> either not logged in or has not already granted the application
> access, a UserConsentException will be thrown.
>
> If immediate is false the user might be asked to login (if he is not
> already logged in) and might get asked to grant the application access
> (if the application hasn't been granted access before). ... The
> returned future will complete with AccessCredentials if the user has
> given the application access to it's data. Otherwise the future will
> complete with a UserConsentException.

**Sample**

Have a look at the exception/promise handling within the sample code:
https://github.com/dart-archive/googleapis_examples/blob/master/drive_search_web/web/index.dart#L36

You'll need something like this:

```
    var id = new ClientId("client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com", null);
    var scopes = [drive.DriveApi.DriveFileScope, drive.DriveApi.DriveScope];

    var responseTypes = [ResponseType.token, ResponseType.idToken];

    // Initialize the browser oauth2 flow functionality.
    createImplicitBrowserFlow(id, scopes).then((BrowserOAuth2Flow flow) {
      flow.obtainAccessCredentialsViaUserConsent(immediate: true, responseTypes: responseTypes).then((AccessCredentials credentials) async {
        handleAccessCredentials(flow, credentials);

      }).catchError((e) {
        print('exception 1: ${e.toString()}');

        flow.obtainAccessCredentialsViaUserConsent(immediate: false, responseTypes: responseTypes).then((AccessCredentials credentials) async {
          handleAccessCredentials(flow, credentials);

        }).catchError((e) {
          print('exception 2: ${e.toString()}');
        });
      });
    });

  static void handleAccessCredentials(flow, credentials) {
    // Credentials are available in [credentials].
    print(
        'received credentials access:${credentials.accessToken}, refreshToken:${credentials.refreshToken} ' +
            'id:${credentials.idToken}');
    flow.close();
  }
```

You should consider using PCKE as it is considered more secure.

**ID/Refresh Token on Back-end**

If you want to use the "code authorization" grant method then you'll need to handle this differently.

The `idToken` and `refreshToken` need to be exchanged your authorization code `accessToken` from the server side with both `clientId` and `clientSecret` set.

https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis/issues/205
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#exchange-authorization-code

This is a different integration pattern between the front-end (Dart, Flutter) and the back-end so you'll probably need some custom cloud functions.